# Vista Internet Explorer 8 Data Execution Prevention kills Internet Explorer 8

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer-8, dep

Just started getting data execution prevention errors. What is the problem?

Comment: Did you change any settings just before?

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by a plugin or add-in that doesn't work well with DEP. Older versions of flash come to mind, but any other badly written software can be causing this.

The addins run within the process space of IE, so it might seem as if IE is causing the DEP violation.

If you are on IE7 or 8, use the addin manager to remove installed add ins and turning them back on one by one until the problem reappears. Then you have isolated the culprit.

Comment: I googled the problem and came up with disabling  some of the add-ons and testing it out now, so far so good.

Answer (score 0):

Virus? Hardware corruption?

Which version do you have? How long has it been installed for? Who uses your computer beside you? Which firewalls do you have installed, antivirus, antispyware? Why do you use IE8 at all? Do firefox, opera, chrome work?

Have you tried adding a DEP exception for IE8? On my system I only get DEP exceptions when the app itself crashes. If it just crashes after adding a DEP exception, it could be a virus.

Comment: Stop using IE8 would not find the cause. I do use them in emergencies but IE8 seems to handle all applications now.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to set up a DEP exception for IE8.  I probably wouldn't just disable it for everyone, but if it's a trusted user:

- Click Start, click Run, type sysdm.cpl, and then click OK.
- On the Advanced tab, under Performance, click Settings.
- On the Data Execution Prevention tab, use one of the following procedures:
- Click Turn on DEP for essential Windows programs and services only to select the OptIn policy.
- Click Turn on DEP for all programs and services except those I select to select the OptOut policy, and then click Add to add the programs that you do not want to use the DEP feature.
- Click OK two times.

[DEP description & details](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/875352)